# "unresolved reference js" in Kotlin file Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to implement a simple JS call for api. But no matter what I do, Android Studio will flag the phrase "js" and say unresolved reference upon building.

For example:

```
import js.*
class exampleClass{
fun function(){
     val grab = js("...");
}}
```

This will cause the error. Even just importing or returning js will cause the error, as it seems that typing js in any context will cause it.

I have seen phrases when searching to enable/disable external builds in the settings of Android Studio ,but that does not seem to work. I have also seen that I can implement Gradle with JS files, but I do not need to use JS heavily.

I have the latest stable release of Android Studio (3.1.4 )
Any help at all is greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: What kind of project is this? The `js` function is available only in projects that are compiled to Kotlin/JS and run in a browser. It cannot be used in Android applications.

Comment: Hi Yole, It is an app development project, thanks for letting me know. I intend to make a call towards an API, do you mind letting me know where I can find information for that specifically? Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: If you need to call an API from an Android application, you should use a library such as Retrofit.